# PHP - Google translation version 2 is not working with PHP curl, what is causing 403 return error?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-translate

I have the ZF first old function working before but somehow ZF it was failing, and then i made the unittest module.

I am trying to use the google translation v2 but it never works anymore, did Google stop there service for public use or is it PHP Bug or somewhere else confusing very much.

Always returning 403 with both following functions.

Any idea whats going wrong?

```
<?php
## Test: How to's
/*
$ php tst.php 
403

$ curl http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate -d "v=1.0&q=dog&langpair=en|ru" -H "Referer: http://google.com"
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", "responseStatus": 403}sun@sun-M14xR2:/var/www/html/vooyz.com/unittest$ 

*/

// V1 - Old not working
function googleTranslatePostV1($text, $destLang = 'nl', $srcLang = 'en') {
  $url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate';
  $http_response = '';
  $text = urlencode($text);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : "");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "v=1.0&q=" . $text . "&langpair=$srcLang|$destLang");
  $http_response = curl_exec($ch);
  $json = json_decode($http_response, true);

  if ($json['responseStatus'] != '200') {
    return $json['responseStatus'];
  } else {
    return $json['responseData']['translatedText'];
  }
  curl_close($ch);
}

// V2 - Curl way not working
function googleTranslatePostV2($text, $destLang = 'nl', $srcLang = 'en') {
  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2';
  $http_response = '';
  $text = urlencode($text);
  $postArr = array('key' => 'sdfdsfdsfds',
          'q' => $text,
          'source' => $srcLang,
          'target' => $destLang);

  $ch = curl_init();    
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=-->this+is+a+test<--&langpair=en%7Car');      
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);       
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : "");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postArr);        
  $http_response = curl_exec($ch);

  var_dump($http_response);

  $json = json_decode($http_response, true);

  if ($json['responseStatus'] != '200') {
    return $json['responseStatus'];
  } else {
    return $json['responseData']['translatedText'];
  }
  curl_close($ch);
}


// V2 - Google way
function googleTranslateV2Method1($text, $destLang = 'nl', $srcLang = 'en') {
  require_once 'google/src/Google_Client.php';
  require_once 'google/src/contrib/Google_TranslateService.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Google Translate PHP Starter Application');
  $client->setDeveloperKey('dsfdsfdsf');
  $service = new Google_TranslateService($client);

  //$langs = $service->languages->listLanguages();
  //print "<h1>Languages</h1><pre>" . print_r($langs, true) . "</pre>";
  $translations = $service->translations->listTranslations($text, 'hi');

  return $translations;
}

echo googleTranslatePostV1("V1: " . "How are you?") . "\n";
echo googleTranslatePostV2("V2: " . "How are you?") . "\n";
echo googleTranslateV2Method1("V2: " . "How are you?") . "\n";


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ curl http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate -d "v=1.0&q=dog&langpair=en|ru" -H "Referer: http://google.com"

{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", "responseStatus": 403}
```

> http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html : 
>  Google
>   Translate API is available as a paid service. See the Pricing and FAQ
>   pages for details.